# Multicast routing

Tags: linux, networking, debian, route, vrrp

I got two firewalls running Keepalived and working ok.
I would like to pass the vrrp multicast traffic bethween a direct back to back link
between those firewalls (that direct link is already used by conntrackd).

In order to do that I did add a route like that :
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth3

Using the command :
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth3

But if I type iftop -i eth0 -f vrrp, I still can see multicast traffic on that link and
no vrrp traffic at all on eth3...

Any idea why my route is ignored ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The VRRP multicast traffic MUST be sent on the interface that vrrpd tracks, otherwise a failure of that network MAY go undetected (you're not only tracking the up/down status of the other host(s), but also their network connectivity).

If your setup is similar to the following:

```
A - s1 - s2 - B
|             |
+-------------+
```

how would you (using the direct link between A and B) detect that the link between S1 and S2 (switches, in this case) goes down?